# arrow function use in setstate

Tags: reactjs

I wrote a piece of code that I don't quite remember how it works, embarrassing to say.

The state is as below:

```
state={
        api:[
            {
                id: 1,
                purpose: "For the Android phone",
                link: "playgoogle/GooglePlay",
                status: "1"
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                purpose: "For the Android phone",
                link: "playgoogle/GooglePlay",
                status: "0"
            }
        ]
    }
```

And this is the snippet of code that I don't quite understand.

```
activateAPI=(id)=>{
        this.setState(prev => ({
            api: prev.api.map(api => api.id === id ? { ...api, status: 1 } : api)
        }))
        this.changeStatus(id,1);
    }
```

I understand that a value is passed into the activateAPI as id but I don't quite understand how the `prev` and `api: prev.api` works here. I understand that the `api` inside the `map` is like a foreach where it checks whether the current item's id in the json array matches the function id then what does `{...api,status:1}` mean?

Any clarification would be much appreciated. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nature of `setState` is async. What you've written is pretty clear that when you call `setState` with its callback signature. Internally once the callback completes, React returns the callback to `setState`. And here's what you're doing,

```
(state, props) => stateChange
```

Above is the true signature of the `setState` that React provides.
State is a reference to the component state at the time the change is being applied.

For more info [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Also when you use spread operator, it spreads the object and updates the prop that is changed. So when you do `{...api, status:1}`. It will compare the API object from the initial one and updates the `status` value to 1.

Remember this will be the shallow comparison. For updating nested state objects you need to go to the nested level to observe proper state update.

Comment: so prev.api is the old state with its properties?

Comment: Correct. It holds the old state context and it traverse through it and while traversing you're spreading the old object and then updating the status value.

Comment: Normally I use setState in this type when my rendering is too fast like I am increasing a quantity using a button.
      this.setState((oldState) => {
            return {
                quantity: oldState.quantity - 1
            }
        });  basically we fetch recently update state and change it

Answer (score 1):

```
 api: prev.api.map(api => api.id === id ? { ...api, status: 1 } : api)
```

That mean , When mapping array if it find the api with the id matched, it with return the new api object with property 'status' change to '1' . If not it will just return the old api object

sorry for my bad english :D hope it help

Answer (score 1):

What the [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) does is that it creates a new object.

So in this case when you are doing `{...api, status: 1}` a new object is getting created with all the keys present in `api` object and then overriding the `status` value with `1` when `api.id === id` is true.

```js
let x = {key: "Key", val: 1, val2: 22}

//spread and update the value, it'll only update `val` all other values wil be as is
console.log({...x, val: 2})
//the original object will be as is
console.log(x)


let y = {z: {key: "Key", val: 3}, z1: 2}
//assign y to y1 by spreading
let y1 = {...y}
y1.z.val = 4;
//z.val in both y and y1 will be modified because spread will not spread deep objects 
console.log(y1)
console.log(y)
```

Coming to the arrow function in [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) will accept a function as first parameter. React will pass `state` and `props` as params to the passed function. This way you will be able to access the `state` in order to update it by using old state.

Below is the `setState` function

```
setState(updater, [callback])
```

The first argument is an updater function with the signature:

```
(state, props) => stateChange
```

> state is a reference to the component state at the time the change is being applied. It should not be directly mutated. Instead, changes should be represented by building a new object based on the input from state and props.
> Hope this helps.

Comment: So to clarify, `{...api, status : 1}` retains all the the other json objects and its properties but changes the status of the json object whose id is matching the api.id?

Comment: @cswannabe, Yes it will not touch the other json properties and only updates the status.